# Implement Resize option to Qt Frameless widget

Tags: c++, qt

How can i implement resize option to Qt frameless widget that it's used as Main Window?

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered this problem as well, and I solved it by adding custom mouseEvent handlers for my QMainWindow. I'm using PyQt, but it should be fairly similar in C++.

In my implementation, dragging the right mouse button anywhere on the frameless widget (called `MyClass`) resizes it.

When the right mouse button is pressed, store the coordinates:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    super(MyClass, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
        self.rdragx = event.x()
        self.rdragy = event.y()        
        self.currentx = self.width()
        self.currenty = self.height()
        self.rightClick = True
```

If the mouse is moved while the button is still pressed (i.e., when it's dragged), resize the QMainWindow. Don't allow it to become smaller than the predefined minimum size.

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    super(Myclass, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
    if self.rightClick == True:
        x = max(frame.minimumWidth(), 
                self.currentx + event.x() - self.rdragx)
        y = max(frame.minimumHeight(), 
                self.currenty + event.y() - self.rdragy)
        self.resize(x, y)
```

When the mouse button is released, reset the button variable to False to stop resizing on movement.

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    super(MyClass, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
    self.rightClick = False
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [QSizeGrip](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizegrip.html)

> The QSizeGrip class provides a resize handle for resizing top-level windows.