# How can i add resize option in QMainWindow that is frameless window in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implement Resize option to Qt Frameless widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128238/implement-resize-option-to-qt-frameless-widget)

I want to add resize option in my QMainWindows that is Frameless window, How can i add this feature to it?

please explain me with code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QSizeGrip](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/qsizegrip.html)

Comment: Thanks for you're reply, when i use QSizeGrip, i can resize my app from one part i.e top left or bottom right. but i want to add this feature to whole window. like default frame. how can i add this feature?