# QT - How to implement to resize Frameless Widget?

Tags: qt, qwidget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implement Resize option to Qt Frameless widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128238/implement-resize-option-to-qt-frameless-widget)

I make a frameless widget using

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

And I want to implement resizing dialog such as Windows.

I found the solution that QSizeGrip is added.

but it makes resizing enabled on right-bottom.

On windows, for example, I can resize on all-sides border(top, bottom, right, left).

How can I implement to resize border like Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the source code of `QSizeGrip`, see what's going on when right mouse button is clicked, and reimplement the function below. E.G. when left mouse button pressed... blah blah

```
virtual void    mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
```

Comment: oh my god... anyone knows simple way?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try using `QSizeGrip`

> Put this widget anywhere in a widget tree and the user can use it to resize the top-level window or any widget with the Qt::SubWindow flag set.